# Integration of WSL with atom ide

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor

Can atom be integrated with WSL like vs code does? For instance i installed platformio-ide-terminal but it opens up in powershell/cmd. Can i open that in WSL and set it as default as I can do it in vs code? Or is it only vs code specific feature which is not available with other ide like sublime text 3 and atom.

> *{ Some people in forms of atom are saying that after Microsoft acquired Github it's development has been slowed down. Should every
>   one switch to vs code? }*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do this all the time with WSL and WSL2 and platformio-ide-terminal.

To install the plugin, type the following at a shell prompt (works just the same with `cmd`, PowerShell and `bash`):

```
apm install platformio-ide-terminal
```

It is important to set the value of **Shell Override** to `C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\bash.exe`. I also set **Working Directory** to **Project**, so the current directory on startup matches the base directory of the project I am working in.